# Simple association won't work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, controller

I have an app I am deploying to Heroku.   Everything seems to work besides the "show" action for my User model.

Here is my code for the user model (what's relevant, anyway)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, 
                  :password_confirmation, :confirmed, 
                  :school_id, :graduation, 
                  :admin, :stars, :credits, :school_name

  has_many :uploads, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :downloads, :source => :user_id, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

  #VALIDATIONS OMITTED

  #WARNING
  before_create :encrypt_password

  #PASSWORD ENCRYPTION METHOD OMITTED

  #getter for school name
  def school_name
    school.name if school
  end

  #setter for school name (will create school if it didn't find one)
  def school_name=(name)
    self.school = School.find_by_name(name) unless name.blank?
  end

  def add_credits(num)
    self.credits += num
  end

  def charge
    self.credits -= 1
    self.save(false)
  end

  def has_downloaded?(file)
    @downloads = self.downloads.find(:all, :conditions => "upload_id = #{file.id}")
    return (@downloads.length > 0)
  end


  private

    #MORE PASSWORD ENCRYPTION LOGIC

end
```

Here is the code for my upload model:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope :order => 'uploads.created_at DESC'

    attr_protected :linked_file_name, :linked_content_type, :linked_size

    attr_accessible :user_id, :stars, :ratings, 
                    :semester, :professor, :year, 
                    :description, :course_id, :school_id

    after_save :set_course_school

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :school
    belongs_to :course
    has_many :downloads, :source => :upload_id, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :comments, :foreign_key => "file_id", :dependent => :destroy
    #belongs_to :class

    #paperclip
    has_attached_file :linked,
          :storage => :s3,
          :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
          :path => ":class/:id/:attachment/:basename.:extension"

    #validations
    validates :school_id, :presence => true

    def update_rating
      @comments = self.comments.all
      if @comments.length > 0
        @stars = 0
        @comments.each do |comment|
          @stars += comment.rating
        end
        self.stars = @stars
        self.ratings = @comments.length
      end
      self.save(false)
    end

    def course_name
      return [course.subject, course.course_code].join(' ') if course
    end

    def course_name=(name)
      @split = name.split(' ', 2)
      @subject = @split.first
      @course_code = @split.last

      @conditions = {
        :subject => @subject,
        :course_code => @course_code,
        :school_id => self.school_id
      }

      self.course = Course.find(:first, :conditions => @conditions) || Course.create(@conditions)
    end

    def set_course_school
      course.set_school
    end

end
```

And here is the controller action:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @uploads = @user.uploads.all
    @downloads = @user.downloads.all
  end
```

Heroku seems to be having some problem with the statement `@user.uploads.all` which works fine locally, here is what the logs give me:

```
2011-12-29T21:57:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/1" for 200.88.103.28 at 2011-12-29 13:57:07 -0800
2011-12-29T21:57:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
2011-12-29T21:57:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2011-12-29T21:57:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed   in 10ms
2011-12-29T21:57:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-12-29T21:57:07+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
2011-12-29T21:57:07+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT     "uploads".* FROM       "uploads"  WHERE     ("uploads".user_id = 1) ORDER BY  uploads.created_at DESC):
2011-12-29T21:57:07+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2011-12-29T21:57:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `show'
2011-12-29T21:57:07+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2011-12-29T21:57:07+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...ROM       "uploads"  WHERE     ("uploads".user_id = 1) ORDER...
```

Any ideas? I imagine the fix is super simple.   What's weird is that I have another Heroku deployed app that uses the exact same user logic (has a show page that gets all the 'posts' of a user) and that works fine.   The code looks almost identical...

I would greatly appreciate a solution to this problem.   I wish I could offer a bounty but I used most of my rep on a big bounty on an Android question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error statement, it looks like the `user_id` column on your `uploads` table is a varchar, not an integer. Postgres (used by Heroku) doesn't automatically cast, as far as I know.

Can you confirm the data types?

Comment: This is the answer, thank you!   It was for some reason cast as a string, must have been a typo by me.